# Why is this mode function returning null?

Tags: php

In the below `function`, when I call

```
mmmr(array(1,2,3,3,4,3), 'mode', 'ceil'); // null
```

it returns `null`. Works fine if I don't set the third (`$round`) argument.

```
mmmr(array(1,2,3,3,4,3), 'mode'); // 3
```

What am I missing? Coffee?

```
function mmmr( array $array, $output = 'mean', $round = false ) {

        switch( $output ) {

                case 'mode':

                if( $round == "ceil" ) {
                    foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
                        $array[$key] = ceil( $value );
                    }
                } elseif( $round == "floor" ) {
                    foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
                        $array[$key] = floor( $value );
                    }
                } elseif( $round == "normal" ) {
                    foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
                        $array[$key] = round( $value );
                    }
                }

                $v = array_count_values( $array );
                arsort( $v );
                foreach( $v as $k => $v ) {
                    $total = $k;
                    break;
                }
                break;


        }

        return $total;

    }
```

Comment: array array_count_values ( array $array ) http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: Or rather you're passing it an array of floats. It can only handle string and int. `Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values! on line 25` Ceil returns a float.

Comment: that was it. I just typecast it with (int) and now it works fine. If you want to put that in an answer I'll mark it correct, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_count_values()` can only count `STRING` and `INTEGER` values. `ceil()`, `floor()`, and `round()` return a float. Casting it to an `int` fixes your problem:

```
<?php

function mmmr( array $array, $output = 'mean', $round = false ) {

    switch( $output ) {

            case 'mode':

            if( $round == "ceil" ) {
                foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
                    $array[$key] = (int) ceil( $value ); // (int)
                }
            } elseif( $round == "floor" ) {
                foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
                    $array[$key] = (int) floor( $value ); // (int)
                }
            } elseif( $round == "normal" ) {
                foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
                    $array[$key] = (int) round( $value ); // (int)
                }
            }

            $v = array_count_values( $array );
            arsort( $v );
            foreach( $v as $k => $v ) {
                $total = $k;
                break;
            }
            break;


    }

    return $total;

}

echo mmmr(array(1,2,3,3,4,3), 'mode', 'ceil'); // Returns 3
```